# Subclass ObservableCollection<T> behaves strange (design view works, emulator not)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have a strange problem with ObservableCollection **in WP7**. I am trying to implement a serializeable collection. I found a good post here: http://kentb.blogspot.com/2007/11/serializing-observablecollection.html

The problem is: It does not work on WP7.
If it simply would not work, I was going to look for other ways.

But its strange, it works "nearly". In the emulator I get:

- Notify about my CurrentItem implementation
- An updated count of the number of items
- NO update notifications for the bound ListBox

**[DEPRECATED, I used wrong class in DesignerContent, stupid mistake]**
In the designer view I get:

- Notify about my CurrentItem implementation
- An EMPTY count without any changes later
- WORKING update notifications for the bound ListBox

The easiest way to test this is to download my test project here:
http://www.filesavr.com/77B1RN0113044J4

The class you have to look at is ObsColl in SimpleTest and the design view of SerializerTestPage in AppA.
Its really strange, it maybe a Silverlight thing, or a WP7 problem.

Anyone know how to solve this, or has a link to an example for an serializable ObservableCollection for WP7?

Thanks,
Chris

PS: Crosspost here, I will update both posts in case of answers:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/76981/467546.aspx

**[EDIT]**
I found a workaround for now, using a wrapper class. It might not be pretty, but it works ok. The wrapper (code below) can be serialized in a normal way (by marking as DataMember) and the ListBox can bind to the DataStorage, and behaves the normal way then.

Currently I only implemented Add() because its only for testing. I should perhaps change the DataStorage to a readonly collection for "external use", otherwise you could make the mistake of trying to add to the DataStorage directly.

Might be all a little confusing, I will try to get the examples a little bit nicer and update this post as soon as I got some time

**[/EDIT]**

```
 public class ObsCollStorable<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged where T : class
{
    public ObservableCollection<T> Storage { get; private set; }
    private List<T> _objects;

    [DataMember]
    public List<T> Objects
    {
        get
        {
            return _objects;
        }
        set
        {
            _objects = value;
            Storage = new ObservableCollection<T>();
            foreach (var s in _objects) Storage.Add(s);
        }
    }


    [DataMember]
    public int CurrentIndex { get; set; }


    public T CurrentString
    {
        get
        {
            if (Storage == null) return null;
            if (Storage.Count <= CurrentIndex) return null;
            return Storage[CurrentIndex];
        }
    }



    public ObsCollStorable()
    {
        Objects = new List<T>();
        Storage = new ObservableCollection<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T t)
    {
        Objects.Add(t);
        Storage.Add(Objects.Last());

        CurrentIndex = Objects.Count - 1;
        if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(""));
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Depriciated? I call that solved.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed a couple of things. The first is that your Design view had a different class providing the DataContext than your runtime.

```
<d:DesignProperties.DataContext>
    <SimpleTests:SerializerTestSimple/>
</d:DesignProperties.DataContext>
```

Changing that to:

```
<d:DesignProperties.DataContext>
    <SimpleTests:SerializerTest/>
</d:DesignProperties.DataContext>
```

Synched up the views. As far as the serializable collection goes, I wasn't sure what you were doing exactly, so I removed ObsColl because it seems unecessary to inherit from a collection when you just wanted to serialize a property. Why not add that property to the View's class and serialize the property when the app suspends? I don't know anything about WP7, so take that advice with my inexperience in mind.

Following that logic, I did this:

```
[DataContract]
public class SerializerTest : INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyCollectionChanged
{
    private DispatcherTimer _dT;
    public static string Key { get{return typeof (SerializerTest).FullName;} }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Strings { get; private set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string CurrentItem { get; private set; }

    public SerializerTest()
    {
        Strings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        Strings.CollectionChanged += StringsCollectionChanged;
        CreateTimer();
    }

    private void StringsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentItem = Strings[Strings.Count - 1];
        OnPropertyChanged("CurrentItem");
    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    public void Init(StreamingContext c)
    {
        CreateTimer();
    }

    private void CreateTimer()
    {
        _dT = new DispatcherTimer();
        _dT.Tick += (a, b) => Strings.Add(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + Strings.Count);
        _dT.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 2);
        _dT.Start();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;
    public void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (CollectionChanged != null)
        {
            CollectionChanged(this, args);
        }
    }
}
```

And updated the binding statements:

```
        <TextBlock 
        Foreground="Red"
        Text="{Binding CurrentItem}"
        Grid.Row="0"></TextBlock>

    <TextBlock 
        Foreground="Yellow"
        Text="{Binding Strings.Count}"
        Grid.Row="1"></TextBlock>

    <ListBox 
        Grid.Row="2"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Strings}"></ListBox>
</Grid>
```

Comment: To add more unsolicited advice, I think you are going to have problems if you have data in your view like this. If it were me, I would try really hard to develop a model for my data that does the serialization and data management. MVVM is key here for keeping your concerns seperated, and your code maintainable.

Comment: Ok, first of all, thanks for your tip regarding the design view, I hate mistakes like that :-) 

For the serializable collection, I want to have an ObservableCollection which I can mark as [DataMember] and which behaves exactly like a normal one, but with "StorageAbility". I have to investigate a little bit more, and regarding the comment, the design is just for testing purposes, of course. For now I found a workaround, I will update the post if I found something more nice (time constraint at the moment, topic postponed for a few days)

Comment: I'm not arguing against serializing the collection, but I'd say that the collection that the view is exposed to doesn't need to be serializable. In fact, I'd avoid exposing the serializable members from outside my model.